# Multiple instances of Qt 3D Entity

Tags: qt, qml, qt3d

I'm trying to create multiple spheres in Qt 3D.

Following is the code I have developed:

```js
Entity{
    
    Repeater {

        model: 10
        SphereMesh {
            id: sphereMesh1
            radius: 1
        }

        Transform {
            id: sphereTransform1
            property real userAngle: 0.0
            matrix: {
                var m = Qt.matrix4x4();
                m.rotate(userAngle, Qt.vector3d(0, 1, 0));
                m.translate(Qt.vector3d(index, 0, 0));
                return m;
            }
        }

        PhongMaterial {
            id: material1
        }

        Entity {
            id: sphereEntity1
            components: [ sphereMesh1, material1, sphereTransform1 ]
        }
    }
}
```

I have written a repeater above to create 10 spheres but the screen is showing blank. Any hints?

Comment: What happens If you place only one sphere? Please provide [mcve] so we can run and test it.

Comment: The qml file [here](https://github.com/qt/qt3d/blob/dev/examples/qt3d/simple-qml/main.qml) is the base code I have taken where there is single sphere plotted.
Explaination and output of the file is [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt3d-simple-qml-example.html#:~:text=A%20QML%20application%20that%20demonstrates,a%20scene%20in%20Qt%203D.)

Comment: I'm not sure how the QML repeater works but maybe it's got something to do with that you're not allowed to share transforms between entities. Have you tried your code without the repeater? Does it work then?

Comment: I guess your use of `Repeater` is incorrect. You must provide a [delegate](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-repeater.html#delegate-prop). If you do that implicitly (as in your example) you have to provide one and only one item. I guess there is just a logical error in your code. Actually it have to be `Repeater { model:10; Entity{ ... } }`

Answer (score 1):

Use [NodeInstantiator](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qt3d-core-nodeinstantiator.html).

```js
Entity {
    id: root

    Camera {
        id: mainCamera
        projectionType: CameraLens.PerspectiveProjection
        fieldOfView: 45
        aspectRatio: 16/9
        nearPlane : 0.1
        farPlane : 1000.0
        position: Qt.vector3d( 0.0, 0.0, -40.0 )
        upVector: Qt.vector3d( 0.0, 1.0, 0.0 )
        viewCenter: Qt.vector3d( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 )
    }

    OrbitCameraController {
        id: mainCameraController
        camera: mainCamera
    }

    components: [
        RenderSettings {

            Viewport {
                normalizedRect: Qt.rect(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0)
                RenderSurfaceSelector {
                    CameraSelector {
                        id: cameraSelector
                        camera: mainCamera
                        FrustumCulling {
                            ClearBuffers {
                                buffers: ClearBuffers.AllBuffers
                                clearColor: "#333333"
                                NoDraw {}
                            }
                            LayerFilter {
                                filterMode: LayerFilter.DiscardAnyMatchingLayers
                                layers: [topLayer]
                            }
                            LayerFilter {
                                filterMode: LayerFilter.AcceptAnyMatchingLayers
                                layers: [topLayer]
                                ClearBuffers {
                                    buffers: ClearBuffers.DepthBuffer
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        InputSettings {}
    ]

    Layer {
        id: topLayer
        recursive: true
    }

    ListModel {
        id: entityModel

        ListElement { x: 0; y: 0; z: 0 }
    }

    NodeInstantiator {
        id: instance

        model: entityModel

        delegate:Entity{

            SphereMesh {
                id: sphereMesh1
                radius:1
            }

            Transform {
                id: sphereTransform1

                translation: Qt.vector3d(x,y,z)

            }

            PhongMaterial {
                id: material1
                ambient: "red"
            }

            Entity {
                id: sphereEntity1
                components: [ sphereMesh1, material1, sphereTransform1 ]
            }
        }

        Component.onCompleted:
        {
            for(var i=0;i<10;i++)
            {
                entityModel.append({"x" : i*3, "y" : 0.0, "z" : Math.random()} )

            }

        }
    }
}
```

[image: Output screenshot]